# Get clicked item: Android

Tags: android, click

I have a dynamically inflated layout.

```
<TableLayout>
   <!-- Two more tablelayout here -->
   <ScrollView>
      <TableLayout>
         <!-- Here a tablerow is added using inflate layout -->
      <TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>
 </TableLayout>
```

The layout for the table row looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
style="@style/savedItemRow">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView 
        style="@style/textviewSaved"
        android:id="@+id/text_item"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_item_responce"
            style="@style/textviewSavedSub" />

</TableLayout>
</TableRow>
```

I would like listen when the text_item id is clicked (Keeping in mind that I have dynamically created tablerows created at run time).

I am an android noob. I am not sure if I asked the question the right way. I want to get the click item's properties somehow during run time so I can manipulate them. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add android:clickable in TexView Layout for making TextView Clickable :

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and in Code Part:

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
text.setText("YOUR TEXT");
text.setId(5111);
text.setClickable(true);
text.setOnClickListener(handler);
View.OnClickListener handler =new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.mytextviewone: // doStuff
            break;
        case R.id.mytextviewone: // doStuff
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add the 'new' keyword on the View.OnclickListener handler =  new View.OnClickListener .